# JS Object: Force Property Value to be a certain Type

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a way to make sure the input for a property is a certain Type? In this example I want to check whether the new Lion has a mane. Is there a way to make sure that the 'mane' value is a Boolean, when creating a new Lion Object?

```
function Lion(height, weight, fur, purr, mane) {
  Cat.call(this, name, height, weight, fur, purr);
  this.name = 'Lion';
  this.mane = mane;
};

var lion1 = new Lion('100cm', '250kg', 'beige', 'ROAAAAAAAAR!', true);
```

Comment: you can check typeof while initialising this.mane

Comment: You could add TypeScript to your project and get transpile time errors if your types dont match. Or when you use it prepend <boolean> to ensure the cast.

Comment: You can create a set method that modifies that variable, and in that method check the type of the data

Comment: Do you want to reject a non-boolean, or convert it to the equivalent boolean?

Comment: I want to reject a non-boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You could force whatever mane is to be a boolean by using `Boolean(mane)` it will output true/false based on Javascript truthy/falsey values and always guarantree mane is a boolean.

```
this.mane = Boolean(mane);
```

Comment: I think `!!mane` is the more idiomatic way to do this. It doesn't call a function or box it into an object.

Comment: Sure the output is the same but for someone not familiar with JS putting !! in front of a variable name is probably not very readable.

Comment: You could link to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript/784946#784946

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `typeof` operator to perform that check when creating the new object:

```
function Lion(height, weight, fur, purr, mane) {
  Cat.call(this, name, height, weight, fur, purr);
  this.name = 'Lion';
  if (typeof mane === "boolean") {
    this.mane = mane;
  } else {
    throw "type error" // or do whatever
  }
};
```

Comment: That seems to work best for me right now(still beginner level). Thank you @nvioli!